# Window function in CASE expression

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am comparing a parameter value with a string in the Expression of a CASE statement and then using window function in the THEN part. However, when my parameter is resolved to a string which is not of the same length as the 'to be compared' value, the sql fails with an 'invalid use of window function' error.

I removed the window function from THEN and just tried to output a string, and it worked without error in both scenarios (parameter resolving to same length and different length strings).

```
SELECT <list_of_columns>
,CASE WHEN 'cod'='code' 
    THEN row_number() over(partition by col1string order by col2string, col3timestamp desc nulls last)
    else row_number() over(partition by col1string order by col3timestamp desc nulls last)
END as rnk
from <tablename>
```

This throws an error:
"ERROR: XX000: unsupported use of window functions"

```
SELECT <list_of_columns>
,CASE WHEN 'code'='code' 
    THEN row_number() over(partition by col1string order by col2string, col3timestamp desc nulls last)
    else row_number() over(partition by col1string order by col3timestamp desc nulls last)
END as rnk
from <tablename>
```

This executes successfully and gives the result

Comment: That use is absolutely valid. Please show us the **complete** query.

Comment: Updated the Question to include the actual SQL with both variations, one which is executing successfully and one which is giving error.

Comment: Works just fine: https://rextester.com/SVAWP82119

Comment: Yes, it worked for me as well last night in one of the online sql editor with postgresql. But unfortunately it is not working in my company's machine. I also noticed that I've not mentioned this is a Redshift database.

Comment: Has the same issue. The difference between working and non-working context that I found was: in non-working difference there were no records that match filters